# Trying to use await in Javascript but it's returning error

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is wrong with this code. It throws an error in the console that says :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my usage of `await`?

```js
let user = {
    name: 'George',
    surname: 'Arqael'
};

let regUser = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
});

let result = await regUser.json();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: As it says, `await` can only be used in an `async` function. Whatever the surrounding function is, mark it as `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Await requires async. You should be able to wrap it in an async function.

```
async function f() {
  let regUser = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
    });
    
  let result = await regUser.json();
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, [top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) is only available in [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). If you add `type="module"` to your script tag it will work as expected.

```html
<script type="module">
  let user = {
      name: 'George',
      surname: 'Arqael'
  };

  let regUser = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
  });

  let result = await regUser.json();
  console.log(result);
</script>
```

Or, wrap your code in an `async` function as [MortBort suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547052/6036546).